# NSFetchedResultsController, NSPredicate to retrieve child objects in to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, uicollectionview, one-to-many, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to figure out if I'm using to the correct predicate to fetch the Item objects for a given Category object with an FRC with the following model and code:

Category <----->> Item

```
NSEntityDescription *entity =
  [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"
              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemLabelText" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

if (self.category.items) {
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@",
                            self.category.items];
  [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

If there are no Items in the Category, I set the number of items in the collectionview to 0.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if ((self.category.items == nil) || [self.category.items count] == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
  [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
  return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

The FRC returns all of the Items in the the object context, not just the ones in the specified Category. I am trying to get the Item objects directly rather than creating/referencing extra attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "usual" (and simpler) predicate to fetch all items for a specified category is

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category = %@", self.category]
```

assuming that "category" is the inverse relationship from "Item" to "Category".

Comment: Thanks Martin, your predicate is definitely the better method.

Comment: With further investigation I found that my problem stemmed from assuming the FRC changed dynamically. I was making changes to the FRC predicate and expecting the output to change on its own. I executed the following code to fix the issue: 
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"]; [[[self fetchedResultsController] collectionView] reloadData];